# Yes/No message box in Odoo

Tags: python, messagebox, odoo

I would like to show a message box with 'text', 'Yes' and 'No' button. If users click 'Yes', to continue the method work.

How could I add this alert message box in my Odoo by Python?

If you have any idea, please share me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to do it via button you can use `confirm` attribute in xml.

```
<button name="cancel_voucher" string="Cancel Voucher" type="object" states="posted" confirm="Are you sure you want to unreconcile this record?"/>
```

Comment: I would like to use in python code... when some condition occurs.. eg. it has unique name for model... I need to check the name that already or not... if already had I will show message with text box for new name that manually type by users..  after that click 'Yes' button... save new name that user typed will save in model... if user click 'No' button, will not do anything.... So can I use this xml code in python code and how do I do? Please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: You can add constraint for the above case. But it will throw only a warning message. If you need the above behaviour you need to go for custom wizard i guess.

Comment: Yeah, I already had sql constraint. I want the above behaviour... so do I need  some xml code for that? Thanks for your explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Call a form view using button (type="action"). In form view footer, keep your button. On clicking on the button do your desired operation.

NB: Your form view model should be different. Should not be same as current view.